# Scala code: Getting type mismatch error when using substring spark sql function?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, substring, type-mismatch

Error occurs at (instr(col("manuscriptpolicy_ext_vehicledescription"),"Registration No.:")+17) since it detects the type to be column and not int as the substring function input is substring(string, int, int). Ive tried casting it to be int but it still detects it as a column. Am I doing something that's causing it to be detected as a column?

```
val registrationNumber =   pc_policy_df.select(col("vehicledescription"),
              when(col("subproduct_ext")==="SpecialRiskOwnDamage" &&
                instr(col("vehicledescription"),"Registration No.:")===0, "")
            .when(col("subproduct_ext")==="SpecialRiskOwnDamage" &&
              instr(col("vehicledescription"),"Registration No.:")>0, trim(substring(col
            ("vehicledescription"),(instr(col("manuscriptpolicy_ext_vehicledescription"),
              "Registration No.:")+17),locate(";",col("vehicledescription"),instr
                  (col("vehicledescription"), "Registration No.:")+17)-(instr
                  (col("vehicledescription"),"Registration No.:") +17) )))
              .otherwise("registrationnumber"))
              .as("R_NUMBER")
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You input to the `trim` function should look more like:

```
trim(
      col("vehicledescription")
        .substr(
          instr(col("manuscriptpolicy_ext_vehicledescription"), "Registration No.:"+ lit(17)), 
          locate(";", col("vehicledescription"))))
```

The `substr` method is defined on `Column` and accepts columns as inputs which is what you want here.